# Handling non null assertions in react native application

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation

I have `authContext` in my react native application with a `token` property, it can be `string | null`.
I have some protected routes, meaning I'm not showing links unless user is logged in and token exists.
On this routes I'm trying to use this token, but TypeScript saying it could be null, which makes sense, but I know that it couldn't.
I know I can use non assertion operator `token!`, but is there an alternative to this problem because it's happening very often often in my code and seems there should be a better way to approach this problem.            Appreciate any thoughts on this, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things that could help

1. Use conditional blocks:

```js
if (!authContext.token) {
  return null
}
// anything after this is going to have TS infer that authContext.token exists
```

2. The non-null assertion operator like you mentioned:

```js
console.log(authContext.token!)
```

3. Redeclaring variable and typing this

```js
const token = (authContext as {token: string}).token
// use token everywhere in this context instead of authContext.token
```